# Error: Package: libmemcached-opt-libs Requires: libevent2

Tags: yum, php7, php-memcached

When I try to run yum update it says libmemcached-opt-libs requires libevent2 but I couldn't find how to install libevent2. When I try yum install libevent2 I get No package libevent2 available message.

Does Anyone has similiar issue on libmemcache update ?

```
[root@XXXX ec2-user]# yum update
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1404 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php72-php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:3.0.4-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php72-php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:3.1.3-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached-opt-libs(x86-64) for package: php72-php-pecl-memcached-3.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php72-php-pecl-msgpack.x86_64 0:2.0.2-4.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php72-php-pecl-msgpack.x86_64 0:2.0.3-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmemcached-opt-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.18-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libevent2(x86-64) for package: libmemcached-opt-libs-1.0.18-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libmemcached-opt-libs-1.0.18-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libevent2(x86-64)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Look at the package exclusions you have put in place.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the comment. I tried yum --enablerepo=* search libevent2 as well. Also I changed repos priorities. But I still get Warning: No matches found for: libevent2 message. Is there anything that I can do to install libevent2 package ?

Comment: Get rid of the package exclusions.

Comment: Reported upstream in https://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=3789 and fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue doesn't exists on CentOS 6, only on *Amzn* altered distribution, which provides libevent version 2 instead of libevent version 1 + libevent2 for version 2

The new build of libmemcached-opt-libs (version 1.0.18-2) improve dependencies handling, and fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick fix. Now yum update works correctly.